# Must "which" be at the start of a subordinate clause?

Tags: subordinate-clauses

To my ears, the following sounds correct:

> Tell me which car you will use.

but the following sounds incorrect:

> Tell me you will use which car.

An [LLM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_language_model) told me they are both correct. Is it right?

Comment: "Tell me you will use which car" is definitely *not* correct.  The LLM may have been trained on faulty data.

Comment: Your intuition is right: the first sentence is right and the second is wrong.  You could fix the wrong sentence with a minor change though: "Tell me (of) the car which you will use" is grammatically correct (but not something that would be commonly said!), although it does not have the same meaning as the sentence from your question.

Comment: You are right. Your second example is ungrammatical since interrogative NPs do not normally function as objects. In any case, it makes no sense.

Comment: Don't use LLMs as grammar checkers.  They are not intended as grammar checkers, and don't have any real understanding of what they are interpreting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer an LLM gives depends heavily on how you prompt it. **Using ChatGPT**, I asked in the following manner:

> Which one is idiomatic English: "Tell me which car you will use", or "Tell me you will use which car", or both?

And the answer is consistent with how both sounds to me although it severely understate the awkwardness of the second version (emphasis mine):

> **Both versions of the sentence are grammatically correct, but the more idiomatic and commonly used phrase in English is "Tell me which car you will use."**
>
> This sentence structure follows a more natural word order in English, where the question word "which" is placed at the beginning of the subordinate clause. The subject "you" is positioned before the verb "will use," which is the standard word order in English declarative sentences.
>
> Example: "Tell me which car you will use." (idiomatic and commonly used)
>
> On the other hand, "Tell me you will use which car" may sound slightly less natural to native English speakers. **It deviates from the typical word order and can sound awkward or less fluent.** However, in informal or poetic contexts, sentence structures can be flexible, and variations like this can be used for emphasis or stylistic purposes.
>
> Example: "Tell me you will use which car." (less idiomatic, but can be used for emphasis or poetic effect)

Now as for a **human answer**:

The first one sounds more natural, because it is based on a question form:

> Tell me, "Which car you will use?"

The second one is only valid as a question if the speaker is incredulous about the other person's choice and puts a heavy emphasis on **which** (thanks, @KateBunting):

> Tell me, "You will use *which* car?"

Comment: This is a great answer!  You have me second-guessing my comments on the question now.  Although, you can get away with almost *any* word order as a matter of poetic effect, so I'm not sure that that qualifies the second version as 'correct' in any other context.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck I agree with you.  ChatGPT does NOT have a real common sense and a sense of perspective that can come only from experience.  Also, it is notorious for protecting itself with disclaimers.  So I edit my answer accordingly and added "although it severely understates the awkwardness of the second version".

Comment: "You will use which car?" is only valid as a question if the speaker is incredulous about the other person's choice and puts a heavy emphasis on **which**.

Comment: @KateBunting I added your comment to the answer